# Laravel queue asynchronously processing events without jobs or listeners

Tags: laravel, eloquent, redis, queue

A lot of my Eloquent models use the $dispatchesEvents configuration to automatically broadcast events after saving, deleting, etc. Sometimes these are picked up and handled by listeners, and sometimes they aren't.

**My queue log seems to indicate that it is processing the event classes themselves as though they were jobs.** This happens even when there is **no listener or other background process** actually doing anything with the event.

Is this the correct behavior or is something misconfigured? Currently it's generating many thousands of queued "jobs" (the event classes) that aren't really jobs but end up creating a huge backlog in the queue, slowing everything down and creating a bottleneck for the real jobs that actually need to be processed.

Comment: For event handling to be async, you should implement ShouldQueue on the listener

Comment: @mrhn I understand that. That's not what I'm asking. I'm talking about events that are not supposed to be handled by any listener, and are not being handled by any listener, still showing up in the queue log (and momentarily occupying a queue process).

Comment: @AdamTheHutt if there is no binding between event and listener - the event "should not" appear on the processed job list. `Listeners` are shown in the processed job lists(defined on EventServiceProvider). If you may share reproducible code and expected result - i can try on my development env.

Comment: Thanks @Ersoy. Just to clarify... If there is a binding between the event and one or more listeners, is the event supposed to show up as its own "job"? I would expect the listener to be logged, but not the event.

Comment: Update on this. I can confirm that there is exactly one listener bound to the event in question, but it does NOT have the ShouldQueue contract. This event is showing up in the queue log every time it fires, but no listeners ever handle it.

Comment: @AdamTheHutt you are right about your first message. AFAIK events don't have async/ShouldQueue behavior unless they have handle method and triggered with `dispatch` instead of `event` helper function. When they have handle method and triggered with `dispatch` then they become `job`.

Comment: Thanks @ersoy. They're being dispatched automatically by the $dispatchesEvent property on the Eloquent models. So if that counts as "dispatching" then that may be the answer.

Comment: I think it uses this method https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7.x/src/Illuminate/Events/Dispatcher.php#L210 but when i said `dispatch` i mean the helper method for the job(queue push), not event's helper method `event`(event fire). If you dig/debug here, it may lead to the source of it.